# ignore regular expressions while using bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command

I'm trying to use this command:

```
for i in $(cat file); do echo "$whatever_text.$i">$i; done
```

which is for making each line a new file, I will get straight to the point here!

I want for bash to ignore the expressions such as "$" because for example if I have a line like this:

```
$a = 'string';
```

or multiple lines like that, it won't be printed like that, bash leaves only 'string'.

Comment: See: [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41646525/6862601).

Comment: What should happen when the file has a line with a `/` ?

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to iterate over the *lines* of a text file is to use the `read` command from a `while` loop.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    echo "$whatever_text.$i" > "$i"
done < file
```

See [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for more details.